# Sync same User Control being used in 2 different windows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I am trying to use the same user control in 2 different Windows.  The goal is that if a control in the user control is changed, it will be reflected in the other window that is using the same user control.  My understanding is that they are not "syncing", because each window has their own instance of the user control.  How can I make both either use the same instance or sync between each other?

To explain better what I need help with, I created a simple project and created 2 xaml windows -- MainWindow and SecondWindow.  I also created a user control called CommonUC.

In the MainWindow, I also added a button that opens the SecondWindow when clicked.  Is there a way to reflect the change of the checkbox in MainWindow if changed in SecondWindow?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Test.UserControls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
<Grid>
    <uc:CommonUC/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,116,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SecondWindow secondWindow = new SecondWindow();
            secondWindow.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
            secondWindow.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

SecondWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.SecondWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Test.UserControls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="SecondWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
<Grid>
    <uc:CommonUC/>
</Grid>
```

CommonUC.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControls.CommonUC"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.UserControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="100">
<Grid>
    <CheckBox Content="CheckMe"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Search the internet for MVVM and WPF data binding. Then bind the properties of two (or more) UserControl instances to the properties of a single instance of a view model class.

Comment: Try setting the CommonUC element that's inside the SecondWindow on the Button_Click method, with the CommonUc instance of the MainWindow. It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally the two windows should have a separate instance of user control and that is being reflected in your example as well. However, if you need to sync the checkbox state of main window with the checkbox state of second window, you can do that with  either of the following approach.

1.) Follow MVVM pattern which is recommended pattern for WPF applications and then bind both the views (MainWindow and SecondWindow) with same model. However, I won't suggest this approach as in future, if you need to add additional logic in any view, it will make your model unmaintainable and model will break single responsibility design principle as well.

2.)  Use EventAggregator pattern wherein your main window will subscribe to checkbox state change event from Second Window. And Second window will publish the state change event as soon as its checkbox state changes.

The second approach is recommended for WPF application as it will make sure that each component in your application is decoupled and has single responsibility